# Error Near AS -sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I'm am using the following query in Sqlite3:

```
SELECT 
  Platform,
  SUM((CASE WHEN Result=='Pass' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumPass),
  SUM((CASE WHEN Result =='Fail' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumFail),
  SUM((CASE WHEN Result=='NoRun' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumNoRun),
  SUM((count(Result) as NumTotal)) 
FROM automation_test_auto GROUP BY Platform";
```

and getting an error

> near "AS": syntax error.

What I want to do is to find the number of pass,fail and norun cases in the database for a specific platform.

A prototype of my table is:

```
Platform, Result
XP,     pass
XP,     pass
Win8,     fail 
Win8,     pass
Win8,     pass
XP,     fail
XP,     fail
Win8,     norun
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Platform,
       SUM(Result = 'Pass') AS NumPass,
       SUM(Result = 'Fail') AS NumFail, 
       SUM(Result = 'NoRun') AS NumNoRun, 
       count(Result) as NumTotal 
FROM automation_test_auto 
GROUP BY Platform
```